# Inner class constructor issue when creating adapter for GridView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-cardview, android-gridview, cardview

I'm trying to add some items into a GridView programmatically but it's not working. I have seen answers for similar questions about this error, but I'm not sure of what should be done in this scenario. Creating an outer class or something else?

`AdapterItem` in `adapter.addAdapterItem(MyFragment.AdapterItem(primeNumber))` returns this error:

> Constructor of inner class AdapterItem can be called only with receiver of containing class

```
class MyFragment : androidx.fragment.app.Fragment() {
    private val primeNumbers = arrayOf("2", "3", "5", "7", "11", "13", "17", "19", "23", "29")

    private lateinit var adapter: MyAdapter

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_linearlayout, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val v = view

        val mainLinearLayout = v!!.findViewById(R.id.my_linearLayout) as LinearLayout
        val cardLinearLayout = LinearLayout(context)

        cardLinearLayout.orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL


        val cardView = context?.let { CardView(it) }
        when {
            cardView != null -> {
                cardView.radius = twoDp.toFloat()
                cardView.setContentPadding(36,36,36,36)
                cardView.layoutParams = params
                cardView.cardElevation = twoDp.toFloat()
            }
        }


        val mTitle = TextView(context)
        mTitle.text = "Prime numbers"
        TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(mTitle, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large)

        val mGridView = com.companyname.appname.MyGridView(context!!)
        mGridView.columnWidth = 100f
        mGridView.run {
            numColumns = GridView.AUTO_FIT
            stretchMode = GridView.STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH
        }
        adapter = MyAdapter(activity!!.applicationContext, 0)
        mGridView.adapter = adapter
        for (primeNumber in primeNumbers) {
            adapter.addAdapterItem(MyFragment.AdapterItem(primeNumber))
        }

        cardLinearLayout.addView(mTitle)
        cardLinearLayout.addView(mGridView)
        cardView!!.addView(cardLinearLayout)
        mainLinearLayout.addView(cardView)

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    }


    private inner class MyAdapter internal constructor(context: Context, textviewid: Int) : ArrayAdapter<AdapterItem>(context, textviewid) {
        private val items = ArrayList<AdapterItem>()

        internal fun addAdapterItem(item: MyFragment.AdapterItem) {
            items.add(item)
        }

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return items.size
        }

        override fun getItem(position: Int): MyFragment.AdapterItem? {
            return items[position]
        }

        override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
            return position.toLong()
        }

        @NonNull
        override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, @NonNull parent: ViewGroup): View {
            val rowView: View = when (convertView) {
                null -> activity!!.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, parent, false)
                else -> convertView
            }

            val tv = rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_gridview) as TextView
            tv.text = items[position].first

            return rowView
        }
    }

    internal inner class AdapterItem // add more items
    (var first: String)
}
```

**GridView class**

```
class MyGridView : GridView {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle)

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        val heightSpec: Int = when {
            layoutParams.height == AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT -> View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE shr 2, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST)
            else -> heightMeasureSpec
        }

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightSpec)
    }
}
```

Comment: You should try to not use an inner class in this context. Try to implement it without access to the fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
adapter.addAdapterItem(MyFragment.AdapterItem(primeNumber))
```

to

```
adapter.addAdapterItem(AdapterItem(primeNumber))
```

or it's long form

```
adapter.addAdapterItem(this.AdapterItem(primeNumber))
```

because that way it's trying to use the internal access via `this.AdapterItem` which uses itself as outer class while your syntax forces it to use the external static way without an outer class.

You could also just drop `inner` from your code entirely - as far as I see - since you don't access the outer class from the inner and that's what `inner` allows.